# In R: while extracting time from date time stamp, wrong results appearing. The better way?

Tags: r

Hi I have the following data time stamp dataframe 'zz':

```
DateTimeStamp
27-08-12 10:33:49
30-08-12 10:03:47
10-09-12 10:59:01
11-09-12 10:48:47
27-08-12 0:00:00
30-08-12 0:00:00
10-09-12 0:00:00
11-09-12 0:00:00
13-10-12 0:00:00
06-11-12 0:00:00
15-12-12 0:00:00
```

When I run the following:

```
strftime(zz$DateTimeStamp[1:5], format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

I am getting the following results:

```
"13:33:49" "13:03:47" "13:59:01" "13:48:47" "03:00:00"
```

These are obviously wrong. What mistake I did?

The local info:

```
sessionInfo() 

R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.1    xlsxjars_0.6.1 rJava_0.9-8    xlsx_0.5.7
```

Comment: It works for me in R 3.3.2

Comment: Also check your sessionInfo() for the locale

Comment: the `str(zz$DateTimeStamp)` results into `POSIXct[1:17418], format: "2012-08-27 10:33:49" "2012-08-30 10:03:47" "2012-09-10 10:59:01" "2012-09-11 10:48:47"`

Comment: Even character strings works for me with `strftime`

Comment: @akrun unfortunately it is not working for me.

Comment: Can you try with `format(zz$DateTimeStamp, "%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: Please show the output of `dput(head(zz$DateTimeStamp))` .

Comment: `format(zz$DateTimeStamp, "%H:%M:%S")` produces `NULL` values :(

Comment: Looks like a time zone issue. Specify `tz` parameters. Also, the print methods look weird, which makes me suspect the above is not actually POSIXct yet.

Comment: `dput(head(zz$DateTimeStamp))` also produces `NULL` values

Comment: oops! I notice `format(zz$DateTimeStamp, "%H:%M:%S")` worked !! thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @akrun and the finally issue resolved. Use:

```
format(zz$DateTimeStamp, "%H:%M:%S")
```